# Tell me how to properly set up the stroke that goes beyond the block

Tags: html, css, shopify

The Shopify store has two 50% blocks
One block has a picture and another block has a text block. I need to make the outline of the text block go beyond the borders of the picture. An example of a block is in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ2Fl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With padding-left, you can customize, what the distance from the left border site to the element is.
Read here for more: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

```css
padding-left: 1em
```